# Redirect incoming from from certain domains to specific address, to another address - Postfix

Tags: email, postfix, smtp

We have a customer support email address: `support@example.com`

We want to redirect any emails sent to that address from specific domains (eg, `@fbi.gov` or `@fcc.gov`) to another address (`directors@example.com`).

This is to 'escalate' contact from certain government agencies above the day-to-day support team so we can ensure they are seen by the right people ASAP.

I can't figure any way in Postfix to redirect/forward a message based on both the sender **and** recipient. We have to do this in Postfix (not with maildrop or other LDA) because our SMTP Gateway (postfix) doesn't do local delivery; it is purely a gateway that forwards incoming mail to our internal mail servers on other hosts.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this with postfwd on your relay.
https://postfwd.org/

Comment: I suspected there wasn't a native way to do internally to postfix. I will have a look at postfwd, thank-you! :)